# In-App Purchase Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am developing an application for android and implemented in app purchase. When I click a button it works fine.

I don't want to show in app purchase dialog one more time when user uninstalls application and installs it again.

Please help me with suitable example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Once your managed product is purchased and you do not use consume, a user owns it forever. So at startup check owned products and draw UI accordingly. A very good [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive).